# How to calculate this exponential integral ?

Tags: integration

How to calculate this integral? :

$$∫(1+a/x)^{x}dx$$

here $a∈ℝ^{∗}$.

Comment: See [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Comment: OP: You consider the accepted answer as answering this question?

Comment: @Did: Yes, but it is better if there is a proof of that.

Comment: OP: It seems to me that you are saying simultaneously $A$ and $\lnot A$. Whatever.

Comment: @Did: No, it is better if there is a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, unless $a=0$.

Comment: Proof? $ $ $ $ $ $